# Arduino SPI clock phase synched with data for all 4 modes, what's wrong?

Tags: arduino, spi

I'm trying to drive the [LTC1664 DAC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1664fa.pdf) from an Arduino (*Mega 2560*). The SPI data and clock coming out of the Arduino is always synched (*rise and falls*) for all 4 modes when the DAC data sheet indicates phasing

I've tried all modes, the SS line on the chip is being brought low during the writes (*as it should*) and I've tried different speeds and **shiftOut(), setClockDivider(), setDataMode(), beginTransaction()** and **endTransaction()**.

Is this a bug in Arduino SPI, something specific to the Mega 2560, should I try an Uno or Due? **Help please!** Code below o-scope traces.

BTW: The 16 bit word I'm trying to transmit is, 0x3600 (*o-scope trace truncated*).

[image: "MODE1"]
[image: "MODE0"]

```
/*
  Test DAC Control

  created 18 Mar 2020 (Covid-19, oppsies)
  by Danny Holstein

*/


// inslude the SPI library:
#include <SPI.h>

void DAC(unsigned short value, unsigned char channel, int SS_Pin, int model);
enum models{LTC1664};
enum models model;

// set pin 10 as the slave select for the digital pot:
const int DAC_SS_Pin = 22;

void setup() {
  // set the DAC_SS_Pin as an output:
  // initialize SPI:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.println("SPI.begin");
  pinMode(DAC_SS_Pin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // go through the six channels of the digital pot:
    for (int channel = 1; channel < 6; channel++) {
        delay(500);
        DAC(128*channel, channel, DAC_SS_Pin, LTC1664);
    }
    delay(1000);
 Serial.println("new loop");
}

/*
  DAC Control

  This function controls an LTC1664 Micropower Quad 10-Bit DAC.

 The LTC1664 is SPI-controlled,and to command it, you send one 16 bit word,
  A3 A2 A1 A0 D9 D8 D7 D6 D5 D4 D3 D2 D1 D0 X1 X0
  |  ADDR   |         INPUT CODE           | DON'T CARE

 The circuit:
  * CS - to digital pin 22  (SS pin)
  * SDI - to digital pin 51 (MOSI pin)
  * SDO - to digital pin 50 (MISO pin, not used in this function)
  * CLK - to digital pin 52 (SCK pin)

 created 18 Mar 2020 (Covid-19, oppsies)
 by Danny Holstein

*/

void DAC(unsigned short value, unsigned char channel, int SS_Pin, int model) {
  // take the SS pin low to select the chip:
    digitalWrite(SS_Pin, LOW); delay(100);
    unsigned short buf, b16;
    unsigned char *c, b; c = (unsigned char *) &buf;
    switch (model)
    {
        case LTC1664:
            if (channel > 4) channel = 0xF;
            buf = (channel << 12) | ((value & 0x3FF) << 2);
            SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
            b16 = SPI.transfer16(buf);
            Serial.print("0x" + String(buf, HEX)); Serial.println("\t0x" + String(b16, HEX) + "\t");
            SPI.endTransaction();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }   
    delay(100);
  // take the SS pin high to de-select the chip:
    digitalWrite(SS_Pin, HIGH);
    // printf("value = 0x%04x", buf);
}
```

Comment: If I read the datasheet correctly, the figure 2 on the datasheet shows that it should be MSBFIRST, not LSBFIRST in your code. SPI_MODE0 is correct.

Comment: I see you try to set the spi clock speed to 1MHz, you should do that with adding `spi.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16)` in your `setup()`, and use `SPISettings(16000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0)` with 16000000 that matching the MCU speed (16MHz) for Arduino Mega.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You're right on the MSBFIRST, I had had that in my code but the last bit of code included the what-if-I'm-reading-this-wrong desperation move (corrected and still not working). The SPI settings comment is useful but doesn't fix the phasing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't related to the Arduino SPI function or phasing issues, the LTC1664 has a CLR pin that I had attached to a GPIO but had failed to command HIGH, it had been floating and inhibiting the chip, command HIGH and everything is good now.